# Count and Sum for various ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the count and sum for the following ranges (10-20, 21-30, 31-40).  How can I modify this query to get that?

```
select count (t.aaa), sum (t.bbb)
from xxx t
where t.qqq IN  ('3')
and t.www like 'A'
and t.eee >= TO_DATE('2008/03/20','YYYY/MM/DD')
and t.eee <= TO_DATE('2009/03/21','YYYY/MM/DD')
and t.ttt >= 10 and t.ttt <= 20
```

The output should look something like this:

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ TRANGE ║ COUNT(t.aaa) ║ SUM(t.bbb) ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ 10-20  ║          340 ║ 4981620000 ║
║ 21-30  ║          239 ║ 3999425000 ║
║ 31-40  ║          199 ║ 4076525000 ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Please post a description of your table xxx with a few rows of sample data and your expected output from that sample data. This will help us understand your question better.

Comment: [Sample](http://www.mediafire.com/?j1759febib926b2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to group by t.www and by each range.  A case can turn each number into a range value which can then be used in the group by.

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN t.ttt BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN '10-20'
   WHEN t.ttt BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
   ELSE '31-40' END TRange
   , count(t.aaa), sum(t.bbb)
FROM xxx t
WHERE t.qqq IN  ('3')
AND t.www IN ('A','B','C','D')
AND t.eee >= TO_DATE('2008/03/20','YYYY/MM/DD')
AND t.eee <= TO_DATE('2009/03/21','YYYY/MM/DD')
AND t.ttt BETWEEN 10 AND 40
GROUP BY CASE 
   WHEN t.ttt BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN '10-20'
   WHEN t.ttt BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
   ELSE '31-40' END;
```

[SQLFiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd93c/2)

Comment: 1st:the question is real.----- 2nd: thx for help. the result was good. but there is something. i want to group by by the ranges. so i will have 2 columns (count t.aaa and t.bbb) and 3 rows ( 10-20 , 21-30 , and 31-40). 6 cell of data and nothing more.

Comment: the result was [This](http://www.mediafire.com/?2lbd70fzxvdh7i8)  . and what i am after is [This](http://www.mediafire.com/?j1759febib926b2).

Comment: Then simply remove t.www from the group by.  I have edited the answer to reflect what you want.

Comment: done. great. now i will interchange code to over 900 t.www . it will do a massive help to have our SWOT marketing strategies. ty so much.

Comment: If possible in Oracle, `GROUP BY CASE` would be substituded by `GROUP BY CALCULATED TRange`, which should simplify the query, specially if the number of ranges is increased.

Comment: @Alex That syntax is not available in Oracle.  It looks useful though and would prevent some subquerying.  What platform is it valid on?